# .NET/C# reading certificate from store cause AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, x509certificate, access-violation

I've getting very strange code exception, which is should work but not work.

I have following code:

```
X509Certificate certificate;
X509CertificateStore store = X509CertificateStore.LocalMachineStore(X509CertificateStore.MyStore);
store.OpenRead();
var certs = new X509CertificateCollection();
Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection findCertificateBySubjectName = store.FindCertificateBySubjectName("localhost");

foreach (X509Certificate tempCertificate in store.Certificates)
{
    if (String.CompareOrdinal(tempCertificate.Subject, "") == 0)
    {
        certs.Add(tempCertificate);
    }
}
```

[image]
Current code runs inside w3wp process under admin rights. But I get exception which you can see on screenshot. I tried many things, give all access to all certificates, change users, reimport certificate.
I will be appreciate for any help or assistance.

Comment: Did you even solve this one? I'm having the same problem at the moment and can't see what's wrong.

Comment: @AndreasLjungström in my case problem was related to IIS pool setting 
"Enable 32-Bit applications", I set it to True and everything start work. You can find this setting under Advanced settings for you application pool